# Iframe tag not working in firefox but it works chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, iframe

I am using EJS template.

Iframe tag is not working in firefox but it works in chrome.

Does anyone know what causes this or any steps I can take to prevent this from happening?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">

    <head>

        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="keywords" content="resources">
        <meta name="description" id = "meta-data-description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/jquery-1.7.1.js?ver=12"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <div id='base-container' class="dashboard-base-container">
    <iframe id="report-iframe" class="org" src="http://gamling.com/dashboard/#/collection/classpage/12345678-1234-1234-1234-12345678/collection/12345678-1234-1234-1234-12345678?session_token=XXX&amp;bgcolor=true">
    </iframe>
    </div>
    </body></html>
```

Comment: any js error in ff console?

Comment: @jai no error occured

Comment: All the XXX stuff makes Firefox think it's porn, and that's not allowed.

Comment: @adeneo I am not using XXXX ????

Comment: It was a joke, you replaced the entire URL with X'es.

Comment: @adeneo yes but i was x'es used for hide my url

Comment: it works in my firefox

Comment: @Hawk have u used EJS?

Comment: i copied your whole code into notepad and ran it

Comment: Which plugins do you have? Try to rename `Mozilla` Folder to `MozillaBak` in `%appdata%`.